# When to go for App Model in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

While learning SharePoint 2013; in some diagrams, i found that we need more than just Sharepoint servers to do app model. we should be hosting the app in separate IIS then connect to Sharepoint Servers.

Is not this costly approach?In such case, why should we go for app model and what is the correct kind of applicable scenario? Please help me understand. Any inputs will be grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some basics things are (Provider Hosted apps)

1. For provider-hosted apps, use any language - like HTML, JavaScript, PHP, or .NET
2. Apps are Safer than Sandboxed Solutions as they are executed outside server environment
3. Apps induce Less Load to server than Sandboxed Solutions ..

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mvpawardprogram/archive/2013/01/21/sharepoint-2013-apps-advantages.aspx

For learning purpose you can use IIS express with Developer site.

Comment: The mentioned article is excellent! thank you. It is very helpful to get started.